# Versioned API Explorer without APIController attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have implemented the [aspnet core api versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation#aspnet-core) as described here

here is some example code

```
 services.AddApiVersioning(
                options =>
                {
                    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(0,0);
                    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                } );

services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
                options =>
                {
                    // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
                    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
                } );
```

Example Controller:

```
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiVersion("1")]
    public class BreadcrumbsController : BaseController
    {
...code removed...
    }
```

Everything works fine if I add the `[ApiController]` attribute to the controllers, but if I remove it then the `IApiVersionDescriptionProvider` returns no results. The VersionApiExplorer seems to find no controllers. Unfortunately adding the `[ApiController]` attribute overrides some filters we have implemented so I do not want to add it to the controllers.

How can I get the Versioned API Explorer to discover the controllers without adding the ApiController Attribute?

Comment: How about adding the `ApiVersion` attribute instead?

Comment: All controllers have the ApiVersion attribute

Comment: I updated the question to indicate that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Digging more, I found in the release documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/releases

> - ApiVersioningOptions.UseApiBehavior is now true by default
>
>   - This might result in excluding your API controllers if    [ApiController] has not been applied
>   - If your API controllers use    convention-based routing, they will definitely be excluded because    [ApiController] cannot be applied

After reading that I added the suggested UseApiBehavior = false (it defaulted to true which was a breaking change) and it works correctly now

```
 services.AddApiVersioning(
                options =>
                {
                    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(0,0);
                    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                    options.UseApiBehavior = false;
                } );
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future